# Entering 0 into a field registers as empty?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['addmonths'])){
    if (!empty($_POST['months'])){
        if (is_numeric($_POST['months'])){
            $monthstoadd = $_POST['months'];
            if ($monthstoadd < 1){
                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET months='lifetime' WHERE username='$lookupuser'");
                echo "Successfully set " . $lookupuser . " to lifetime";
            }elseif ($monthstoadd > 0){
                $monthstoadd = $monthstoadd*2592000;
                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET months=months+'$monthstoadd' WHERE username='$lookupuser'");
                echo "Successfully added " . $_POST['months'] . " months to " . $lookupuser . "'s paid time.";
            }else{
                echo "Error.";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Months need to be numeric. If you're trying to set lifetime, use 0.";
        }
    }else{
        echo "You didn't enter anything.";
    }
}
```

When I enter 0, it should set the user to lifetime, but instead it just echos `You didn't enter anything.` Not really sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the type to make sure it is empty instead of registers as empty with `===`.

`if ($_POST['months'] !== ''){`

This checks to see if it exactly equivalent to empty. If it isn't it passes.

Answer (score 2):

> Entering 0 into a field registers as empty?

Yes, it does. From [the docs for `empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> "" (an empty string)
>   
>  0 (0 as an integer)
>   
>  "0" (0 as a string)
>   
>  NULL
>   
>  FALSE
>   
>  array() (an empty array)
>   
>  var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
>
> Any ideas?

`empty` doesn't seem like a good match for the condition you're checking for (did they type something in). Since you're already apparently using a marker field to indicate that there *should* be a value there, you might consider [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and a check against a blank string:

```
if (trim($_POST['months']) != ''){
```

Since you'r using `$_POST['months]` in four different places, I'd probably also cache the trimmed version to a local variable.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: To extend on this answer, include a check to see if the value is exactly 0: `if (!empty($_POST['months']) || ($_POST['months'] === 0)){`

Comment: @Rob: It answers the question you asked in your title, which is meant to summarize your overall question (I took the "Any ideas?" at the end to mean "any ideas why `empty` isn't working?"). I've added something to address how you might fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, You can substitute `empty` for `isset` (which returns `false` only of the variable doesn't exist or is `null`) or `array_key_exists` (for array keys).

In this case, you can do

```
if (!isset($_POST['months']) || $_POST['months'] === "")
```

Alternatively

```
if (!array_key_exists('months', $_POST) || $_POST['months'] === "")
```

Since this is POST data, `null` will never be a value (the browser can either not send the input or it sends an empty string, which PHP translates to `""`). Therefore, `isset` and `array_key_exists` are interchangeable. `isset` is, however, preferred, since it's not a function and therefore is faster to run (not mention it's faster to write it).